# Split into two variables?

Tags: php, string, parsing, explode

Say I have the following: `"44-xkIolspO"`

I want to return 2 variables:

```
$one = "44";
$two = "xkIolspO";
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Remember, the manual lists every function you could ever want: http://php.net/ref.strings

Comment: Well, unless you know how many variables you must get, `list()` may render quite useless. Manual assignment is better. In such cases, use a `foreach()` to create an array of values.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this:

<del>list($one, $two) = split("-", "44-xkIolspO", 2);</del>

```
list($one, $two) = explode("-", "44-xkIolspO", 2);
```

Comment: Awesome, except that [split is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). A more future-proof solution would probably be [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: use preg_split("/-/", "44-xkIolspO");

Comment: Updated the post to use explode. Hope its not deprecated yet.

Comment: According to http://micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split using preg_split is 69% faster.

Comment: @MikeKormendy when you read the article it says "f2 is slower than f1 by 68.73% " where f2 is the preg_split and f1 is the explode.  So, unless I'm missing something obvious, the article is saying that explode is 69% fater than preg_split

Answer (score 11):

PHP has a function called [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) splits a string using a regular expression. This should do what you want.

Or [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) might be easier.

```
    $str = "44-xkIolspO";
    $parts = explode("-", $str);
    $one = $parts[0];
    $two = $parts[1];
```

Comment: I don't think preg_split is anywhere near necessary in this case.  Regular expression parsing is much less efficient than a delimiter string.