# Split Variable's Data Into Separate Variables

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split into two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731351/split-into-two-variables)

I have a variable that will output two words. I need a way to split this data into two separate words, and specify a new variable for each separated word. For example:

```
$request->post['colors']
```

If the output is string `"blue green"`, I need to split those two colors into separate variables, one for *blue* and one for *green*,
...eg `$color_one` for *blue*, and `$color_two` for `green`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`explode()` them on the space and capture the two resulting array components with `list()`

```
list($color1, $color2) = explode(" ", $request->post['colors']);
echo "Color1: $color1, Color2: $color2";

// If an unknown number are expected, trap it in an array variable instead
// of capturing it with list()
$colors = explode(" ", $request->post['colors']);
echo $colors[0] . " " . $colors[1];
```

If you cannot guarantee one single space separates them, use `preg_split()` instead:

```
// If $request->post['colors'] has multiple spaces like "blue    green"
list($color1, $color2) = preg_split("/\s+/", $request->post['colors']);
```

Comment: That works a treat! Thanks a lot for that. Also, what if the output is blue green yellow (and so on)? Would it simply take the first two words for the variables?

Comment: @ASmith If you don't know there will be only two, don't use `list()`. Instead capture in an array variable. See changes above.

Comment: Thanks for the great help and advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an array with explode too:

```
//store your colors in a variable
$colors=" blue green yellow pink purple   ";

//this will remove all the space chars from the end and the start of your string
$colors=trim ($colors);
$pieces = explode(" ", $colors);
//store your colors in the array, each color is seperated by the space

//if you don't know how many colors you have you can loop the with foreach

$i=1;
foreach ($pieces as $value) {
     echo "Color number: ".$i." is: " .$value;
     $i++;

}
//output: Color number: 1 is: blue
//        Color number: 2 is: green etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help and advice.

Comment: You welcome ,my pleasure to help